# Is it possible to view WP documentation within the WordPress shell?

Tags: wp-cli, documentation

I'm having trouble navigating the WP documentation so forgive me if this is common knowledge.

Is it possible to view the documentation of classes and methods from within the shell?

That is, is there a command that I can type at the `wp-shell` prompt that will return the api documentation for a given method/class.

Something like:

```php
doc(get_posts);
#=> get_posts( array $args = null )
# Retrieves an array of the latest posts, or posts matching the given criteria.
# Parameters
# $args
# ...
```

For example, `pry-doc` in Ruby provides something similar.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Which documentation? What shell?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more explicit.

Comment: I guess in theory one could create a custom wp-cli command/function with `wp_remote_get()` on e.g.  https://developer.wordpress.org/, then parse it with e.g. `DomDocument` and hope the HTML is well structured and similar across the pages  :-) It would be an interesting idea to have https://developer.wordpress.org/ available in other formats than HTML. I haven't checked though.

Answer (score 1):

Skimming the available [WP-CLI commands](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/) I guess there is not something like that. You may create a feature request in the [WP-CLI GitHub repo](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli) but I doubt that this will gain much attention without you explaining the actual necessity of such command.

Normally when developing, you use your IDE to get hold of those information. A good IDE provides you autocompletion, type hints or shortcuts that let you jump into certain core functions.

Naming [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) as an example which has built-in WordPress support it looks like this when I just start to type `wp_`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try [WP-CLI Reference Command](https://github.com/mehrshaddarzi/wp-cli-reference-command). This is neither an official command, nor can it be used inside `wp shell`, but will be helpful to you in getting hook / function information from command line.